# Google Chart - first item from continuous horizontal axis not showing

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm drawing a linechart with Google Chart. The first "column" from is a date, so the horizontal axis is a continuous axis. It works fine, but one problem: I want that the label from the first row is shown.
Reading the documentations [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Discrete_vs_Continuous) all the charts with continuous horizontal axis hide the first row.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the chart's choice of axis labels by using the `hAxis.ticks` option, which takes an array of values or objects.  Values represent the locations to place a tick mark at, and must be of the same type as the domain column (date, datetime, timeofday, or number).  Objects have two properties: `v`, the value to place the label at (mandatory); and `f`, the label to use at that value (optional).  Any elements that do not specify a label will be formatted using the axis formatting.

As an example:

```
hAxis: {
    format: '#.00',
    ticks: [1, {v: 2, f: 'foo'}, {v: 4, f: '$4'}, {f: 5, f: '5'}, {v: 9.6}]
}
```

will produce an axis with labels at 1, 2, 4, 5, and 9.6, with the labels "1.00", "foo", "$4", "5", and "9.60".  The labels at 1 and 9.6 were formatted according to the `hAxis.format` option I specified, while the others use the labels I specified in the objects.

Comment: I was expecting the API had any option to do this instead of forcing me to explicit the hAxis ticks, but it worked too (with a little more work). Thanks!

Comment: The alternative would be to change the `hAxis.viewWindow.min` option to move the min axis value below your starting value, which would give the axis space to draw a label there, but there is no guarantee that the chart would choose to put a label at that point.